# How to convert Date string to sql date format

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I want to insert the following into database in sql time date format.

```
Sat May 02 19:01:30 PDT 2015
```

Here is my code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
Date formattedDate = calendar.getTime();
Date = formattedDate.toString();
javaSqlDate = new java.sql.Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());
```

I am inserting the value like below:

```
ps.setTimestamp(7, javaSqlDate);
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Are you getting an error message, or is the date stored incorrectly?

Comment: If your are inserting a `TimeStamp` (and the column is a `TimeStamp`) then there should be no problems, the format is irrelevant as the driver and database will figure out what they want and perform the translations themselves.  Time/Date don't carry format, they are just the amount of time that has passed since a anchor timer (such as the Unix Epoch)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    System.out.println("utilDate:" + utilDate);
    System.out.println("sqlDate:" + sqlDate);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For inserting a timestamp that matches the JVM's current system time, you can simply do this:

```
ps.setTimestamp(7, new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```